# Wordpress and Hosting

Tags: wordpress

Is it safe to share my hosting to my friend? My plan is to share it with him, i will add his domain and install wordpress for him. I will not give him the user/pass for the hosting and i will not give him ftp account.

I just want to know that is it safe? He can only access is the admin page of wordpress. Is there a way that wordpress can delete server files if he want to? Like for example he install fil editor plugin on his wordpress account and edit a php file on his wordpress theme, then add code that can affect server or a code that can delete server files by just running that php file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe. Yes, he will be able to make changes to the server. You are basically giving him access to edit a PHP file on the server. With this alone, he can basically do anything he wants just like you said.

Since you're asking this question, I would advise not to share your hosting to your friend.

Get him to sign up on WordPress.com instead. Not to mention getting a simple WordPress site up and running is cheap and easy.

Comment: What if i edit the core code of wordpress to hide some items on the admin page?

Comment: @user1578707 In this case you have to disable these funcionalities - Install plugin and themes - Update core, plugins, themes So for the case is a better option to create a site on wordpress.com will have options

Comment: Im thinking of that thing too. Im the full admin of that wordpress admin page then i will install a plugin that can restrict access to that function for other user. Is that ok?

Comment: @user1578707 Hiding does not mean inaccessible. And it will be a lot of work. Ultimately, it's your decision to make. Unless you trust your friend, I would advise not to do so. You can of course limit your friend's access to the WordPress instance you install as well. As long as you do not allow file editing and installing custom plugins, it should be significantly safer (not entirely safe).

Comment: What is more safe? That method or by just editing the core code of wordpress so i can restrict some function?

Comment: @user1578707 I don't think you have to go into the core code to implement user roles & permissions. There are also plugins to help you manage users' roles easily. Setup an instance and play around as you go until you're comfortable with what you have. Capabilities up to Administrator role except single site Administrator's capabilities should be safe to be granted. https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't safe. At least not the way you mentioned. As you thought, he could put a malicious PHP file in his own theme, and you can't really do anything about it aside from removing his privileges that allow him to install plugins, themes, and update core, plugins, or themes.

However, there is a safe and simple way to do it. Create an account on the computer specifically for your friend, and create a directory inside the home directory in which the WordPress installation files would be kept. Then, when you configure the site, set the DocumentRoot to that path. You'll have to run the command below to give Apache (and therefore WordPress) access to write to that directory.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/directory
```

As far as I know, this removes any security issues. I'll do further research and testing on it when I can, but I think your pretty safe with the above setup. Note that I may be wrong, but I believe this is a typical setup for hosting sites. I'm not 100% sure this is accurate, but from my logic it should be fine. I'd ask this question on the WordPress forums as well, there will be plenty of people there who definitely know WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a sub-domain, new DB user and a new FTP for that sub-domain. provide limited access to DB and FTP user. it will be sufficient for him.
Don't share c-panel detail with him.